# How to sort a body of text in PHP

Tags: php, string, sorting, text

So I'm really new to PHP and I'm trying to learn som new tricks and i hope you guys could help me.

I'd like to use this body of text for example:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit quisque facilisis tincidunt finibus aliquam id tempor elit ut in massa quis nisi dapibus tempus class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra per inceptos himenaeos in ac metus eget."

and first make it appear as it is here, but then also sort the words alpabeticaly and display the results under the original text. Is there a way to make this happen in a simple way?

Thanks!

Comment: There probably is, have you tried anything youself yet?

Comment: I've managed to do it manually with arrays, but thats not really what I'm looking for. I would need it to take the string, slice it up into words and then sort 'em. But as I've said I'm no PHP wizard exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could explode the string into an array by spaces, sort it and implode it back into a single string.

Something like that:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit quisque facilisis tincidunt finibus aliquam id tempor elit ut in massa quis nisi dapibus tempus class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra per inceptos himenaeos in ac metus eget.";
print $string;
// Explode string by spaces
$words = explode(' ', $string);
// Sort the array of words
asort($words);
// Join the elements of the array with spaces
$string = implode(' ', $words);
print $string;
```

Hope this helps! For Detailed info on array sorting check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

EDIT:

From the comment I've seen you don't want to do it 'manually'. You could wrap it into a function like this:

```
$string = 'Beta Alpha Gamma';

function sortWordsInString($string, $glue = ' ') {
    $words = explode($glue, $string);
    asort($words);

    return implode($glue, $words);
}

$string = sortWordsInString($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<?php

$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit quisque facilisis tincidunt finibus aliquam id tempor elit ut in massa quis nisi dapibus tempus class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra per inceptos himenaeos in ac metus eget.";
echo $text."\n\n";
$pieces = explode(' ', $text);
natcasesort($pieces);
echo implode(' ', $pieces);
```

You basically need to `explode` the entire text into words. And from there you `natcasesort` the returned array alphabetically. And lastly you `implode` the array.